# Adding filtering / dropdown menu in AmCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a database with the share of workers by type of jobs for 3 different countries - France, Italy and Spain - (I invented the numbers).

I would like to have a bar chart with a filtering/dropdown menu that allow selecting which country to represent on the figure. See the example below.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

I have a CodePen with my data and figure: https://codepen.io/European-DataLab/pen/LYpxqwG?editors=0010

My code is:

```
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [
  {
    "group": "High blue collar",
    "France": 10.5,
    "Italy": 9.8,
    "Spain": 11
  },
  {
    "group": "Low blue collar",
    "France": 26,
    "Italy": 22.5,
    "Spain": 23.9
  },
  {
    "group": "High white collar",
    "France": 36.8,
    "Italy": 35,
    "Spain": 33.9
  },
  {
    "group": "Low white collar",
    "France": 28.3,
    "Italy": 17,
    "Spain": 36
  }
];

// Create axis X
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "group";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -45;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "top";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "right";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

// Create axis Y
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "%";


// Create series for column
var series1_1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series1_1.dataFields.valueY = "France";
series1_1.dataFields.categoryX = "group";
series1_1.strokeWidth = 0;
series1_1.fillOpacity = 0.7;
```

[image: filtering menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the filter by changing the series' `valueY` field to the value specified in your dropdown and then calling `invalidateData` on the chart:

```
document.getElementById('filter').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  series1_1.dataFields.valueY = e.target.value;
  chart.invalidateData();
});
```

Demo:

```js
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [
  {
    "group": "High blue collar",
    "France": 10.5,
    "Italy": 9.8,
    "Spain": 11
  },
  {
    "group": "Low blue collar",
    "France": 26,
    "Italy": 22.5,
    "Spain": 23.9
  },
  {
    "group": "High white collar",
    "France": 36.8,
    "Italy": 35,
    "Spain": 33.9
  },
  {
    "group": "Low white collar",
    "France": 28.3,
    "Italy": 17,
    "Spain": 36
  }
];

// Create axis X
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "group";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -45;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "top";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "right";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

// Create axis Y
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "%";


// Create series for column
var series1_1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series1_1.dataFields.valueY = "France";
series1_1.dataFields.categoryX = "group";
series1_1.strokeWidth = 0;
series1_1.fillOpacity = 0.7;

document.getElementById('filter').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  series1_1.dataFields.valueY = e.target.value;
  chart.invalidateData();
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<select id="filter">
  <option>France</option>
  <option>Italy</option>
  <option>Spain</option>
</select>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```